# Giving self built magic-functions higher precedence in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, function, oop

I have this class:

```
class newMul:

    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr


    def __mul__(self, obj) -> float:

        return (self.attr * obj) ** 0.5 -1
```

Which defines an object and how it's being multiplied.
I want this multiplication function to have a higher precedence than the r-mult function.

For example:

```
mulObj = newMul(6)
print(6 * mulObj * 5 )
```

I want it to work like this:

first we do `mulObj * 5` then multiply the result by `6`
And so the result would be: `26.8`
Without parenthesis (which is the obvious answer)

The code above returns `25.0` because it is doing `6 * mulObj` which returns `5` and then it does `5 * 5`, even if I add another magic function, `__rmul__`:

```
class newMul:

    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

    def __mul__(self, num) -> float:

        return (self.attr * num) ** 0.5 -1

    def __rmul__(self, num) -> float:

        return (self.attr * num) ** 0.5 -1
```

It still returns `5`

I would appreciate help!

Thank you!

Comment: you can mnually add () around it - I can think of no way to change the [operator-precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) because you would need to change the way pythons expressions are evaluated.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you sir!

Comment: What is the use case?